# Complete Web Deploy Package -> Web Application and Data Project

Tags: asp.net, iis, msdeploy, dacpac

The product I’m trying to create a package out of is a Web Application and a Database Project. This Package needs to be deployed to multiple IIS Web Sites which individually has their own application pool and bindings. In the end I would want the package to be built by a TFS Build Server into a .zip file which via msdeploy.exe somehow can be deployed to these web sites by settings the web site, application pool, binding and destination database in deploy time. It should create if items does not exists and update if they do.

I’ve been researching quite a lot on Web Deploy 3.0. Most of the stuff I find on the internet via google is about defining the package and publishing from within Visual Studio which is not exactly what I want because I want to be able to have control over the settings at deploy time. 
So far I can create a package relatively simple via the Publish dialog in Visual Studio 2013. I can even add my SSDT project dacpac file to the package using the “Update Database” checkbox in the Publish window. But I think a lot of things happen behind the covers which doesn’t seem logic how to do manually.

Ultimately the questions I have right now which I hope someone can help me with is:

- How do I define dbdacfx settings in deploy time when deploying a
  package? (Ie. Target sql server, database, username and password.) Or
  can I parametrize these settings somehow into a parameter.xml file? 
  Can I use the publish profile xml file from my SSDT project?
- How do I make my package create a new web site if it does not exists?
  I can only find information about creating applications under already
  existing sites.
- When and if I create a web site via the package, how do I define the
  associated application pool? Like creating it if it doesn’t exist or
  update it if the target framework is incorrect?
- I’ve read about providers. For instance appPoolConfig provider but
  how to utilize this at deploy time isn’t very clear to me – can
  anyone elaborate or perhaps point to a source explaining it?
- Is there any good books covering this area or perhaps even a better
  alternative?